# Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out how to translate this from Bs3 to Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="input-group date">
    {% include "bootstrap_datepicker_plus/input.html" %}
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I read that `gyphicon` has been dropped so I replaced it with `fa fa-calendar` and added the appropriate stylesheet.

I can't get that button working - which was the `glyphicon`

Answer (score 2):

As per your question I think you are using Font Awesome Icons

For including font-awesome library follow following link:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Even as per latest Font awesome CDN package 5

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

class for the calendar has been renamed to `far fa-calendar` as shown in [link](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=calender&m=free)

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this. Please, note, you haven't stated which version of font-awesome you are using. I assumed [this](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/calendar/)

```
<div class="input-group date">
    {% include "bootstrap_datepicker_plus/input.html" %}
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use feather icons from [here](https://feathericons.com/) (Github link [here](https://github.com/feathericons/feather)) instead of glyphicons in Bootstrap 4. The following code example might be of some help to you.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-feather="calendar">Calendar</div>

    <!-- Icons -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      feather.replace()
    </script>
</body>
```